# Android.net.uri to string and back again

Tags: android, imageview, uri, drawable

I want to save an image to my sqllite database as a string and then get it back and place it in an imageview.

This is what i do:

```
task.Image = uri.ToString();
```

i take the uri and convert it to a string and save it in my database. 
Then i get it back from the database and wants to place it in my imageview again but it doesn't work. I get the task.Image backs and it looks almost good. Somehow it misses the drawable attribute.

```
 Android.Net.Uri ur = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(task.Image);
            _imageView.SetImageURI(ur);
```

The _imageView does have its drawable object until i do _imageView.SetImageURI(ur); after that it is gone.

not the best image but you can se the Drawable is null.

[image]

Is it not possible to save Android.net.uri as a string and then parse it back? Is there some other way i can do it?